# Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxOrganizationServiceWrapper' to type 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy'

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

Could anyone help me with this error?
It is happening in a Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015 Online Plugin.

It's a late binding implementation...

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault,
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: **Unable to cast object of type
>   'Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxOrganizationServiceWrapper' to type
>   'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy'**.Detail: 
>   
>   -2147220891   
>       
>         OperationStatus
>         0
>       
>       
>         SubErrorCode
>         -2146233088
>             Unable to cast object of type
>   'Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxOrganizationServiceWrapper' to type
>   'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy'.
>   2015-03-25T19:31:18.5408758Z
>
> [JHSF.CRM.Principal:
>   JHSF.CRM.Principal.Application.Plugin.PluginAdesaoFidelidade]
>   [dd59ba6a-7ad1-e411-80de-c4346bb59e2c:
>   JHSF.CRM.Principal.Application.Plugin.PluginAdesaoFidelidade: Create
>   of jhsf_adesao_programa_fidelidade]
>
> Error      : **Unable to cast object of type
>   'Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxOrganizationServiceWrapper' to type
>   'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy'**. StackTrace:
>   at SDKore.Xrm.CrmServiceProvider..ctor(String OrganizationName,
>   Nullable`1 IsOffline, Object Provider)

Comment: Please show the code that is triggering this issue. Unless this is a seperate plugin (not code written by you), in that case StackOverflow is not the right site to ask this. Try browsing through the list of StackExchange websites, there's sure to be one related to using (Microsoft) software!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preferably, you should not be referencing `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy` in a plug-in. This is, as the word **Client** indicates, for client-side not server-side code.

That said, you cannot make the cast you reference above and I don't think you can create an `OrganizationServiceProxy` in a sandboxed plugin. If you are using early-bound entities you can create an `OrganizationServiceContext` - from the client DLL - by passing in the instance of `IOrganizationService` available to your plugin.

Comment: @FranciscoAvelino, correct. You shouldn't use the Client DLL in your plugins at all if you can avoid it, as the CRM installation doesn't include that DLL in the bin folder.

Comment: @FranciscoAvelino - correct. Why are you using `OrganizationServiceProxy`? What is it that cannot do with `IOrganizationService`?

Comment: @Nicknow, I think OrganizationServiceProxy gets handy when it is about retrieving access token from it. Which currently I'm trying to get, but OrganizationService does not provide that. And it is throwing the same error to me.